# YouTube HTTP 429 Too Many Requests only on a single PC?

Tags: http

I know that some others lately have been getting "HTTP 429 Too Many Requests".

Yet I am having a strange issue with it that I have not seen here nor on streamlink nor youtube-dl's issue tracker.

On my older Vista PC that I use youtube-dl or streamlink at times to get a video have randomly gotten this error since Thur 11/28.

Strangely though, both programs on my Ubuntu 18.04 do not give this error ever.

How exactly is YouTube tracking which PC is sending them the request? I mean both requests would use my same public IP yet Vista is refused even if I don't request for 24+ hours but Ubuntu always works?

Comment: Differences in HTTP headers can be used to fingerprint different client implementations.  For instance, the `User-Agent` header is often used for identifying different types of clients.

Comment: I tried various User-Agents but they all seem to be denied. I even tried to give the Ubuntu User-Agent String.